# Show Image Preview + Show Dimensions

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am trying to add an image cropper to my site, while also sending the image dimensions for processing when the image is sent to be cropped. I can get the image to show up in the preview box, but I cannot get javascript to output my image dimensions.

My script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function PreviewImage() {
            var oFReader = new FileReader();
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("id_avatar").files[0]);

            oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                document.getElementById("avatar_preview").src = oFREvent.target.result;

            };

            var imgheight;
            var imgwidth;

            function getDimensions() {
                imgheight = image.height; 
                imgwidth = image.width;
                document.getElementById('image_dimension').value = ('The image size is ' + imgwidth + ' x ' + imgheight );
            };

            var image = new Image();
            image.src = document.getElementById('avatar_preview').src;
            image.onload = getDimensions();

        };

    </script>
```

And my HTML:

```
<input type='file' id='id_avatar' name='avatar' onchange="PreviewImage();" /><br />

<div id="parent" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; overflow: hidden;">
    <img id="avatar_preview" src="#" alt="your image" style="width:400px;" />
</div>

<input type='text' id='image_dimension' name='image_dimension' />
```

This code gives me "This image is 0 x 0" in the image_dimension text field.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path but you need to use the `Image` object.
Instead of

```
var image = document.getElementById('avatar_preview').src;
```

You should do

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = document.getElementById('avatar_preview').src;
```

Finally, you should leave your `onload` callback as is.

As a side note, you should insert this line

```
document.getElementById('image_dimension').value = ('The image size is ' + imgwidth + ' x ' + imgheight );
```

inside the callback function as the image is loaded asynchronously.

Check out
[How to get image size (height & width) using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript/626505#626505)
and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image

Comment: If I move the document.getElementById('image_dimension').value into the callback, then I get nothing whatsoever in the text box. I'm updating my code to show.

Comment: @JasonBoyce, remove 'return true;' from the callback at the end of imgheight = this.height; imgwidth = this.width; return true;

Comment: I removed "return true" and changed the variables from "imgheight = this.height;" and "imgwidth = this.width" to "imgheight = image.height;" and "imgwidth = image.width;" which gives me "The image size is 0 x0" which is better than undefined but still not the actual image. It is improving though!

Comment: @JasonBoyce, no, return it to imgheight = this.height.  For image.onload = getDimensions(); change it to image.onload = getDimensions; by removing the paranthesis at the end. Then it should work

Comment: Hold on my previous comment was incorrect. It seems to work on the 2nd time I select an image to upload, but not the first.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the image size using Javascript.

**1. Instantiate a new Image:**

```
var img = new Image();
```

**2. Set the image source:**

```
img.src = document.getElementById('avatar_preview').src;
```

**3. Now to get the width and height just use:**

```
img.width
img.height
```